# Outlook with GSSMO: Rare case of email received hours later than in Gmail, receipt time incorrectly shown

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, google-workspace

This is an issue with MS Outlook using G Suite Sync for Microsoft Outlook (GSSMO). Here's what happened according to the email header:

#### Background

1. The Sender sends an email at a local time that translates to `Mon, 2 Mar 2020 01:32:45 UTC`
2. The Gmail server receives the mail about 2 hours later at `Mon, 2 Mar 2020 03:49:35 UTC` (Translated from PST)
3. On Gmail, the email was received at `Mon, 2 Mar 2020 03:49 UTC` and shown in the inbox.

#### The issue:

1. In Outlook, the same email did not show up until after `Tue, 3 Mar 2020 00:00 UTC` when Outlook is restarted.
2. In Outlook, instead of showing the actual time of receipt, it shows `Mon, 2 Mar 2020 01:33 UTC` as the date of receipt. Which is even before Gmail receives the mail. I am not sure whether this is the Sender's machine time, or the actual server time.

#### Question:

1. What is stopping Outlook to show this email in the inbox?
2. How to set up Outlook so that it shows the correct date/time of receipt?

Comment: You may post this issue in Gmail support forum. This may be a behavior in GSSMO.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Aidan.

Comment: My understanding of the email spec is that the time received is meant to be the time the message arrived _locally_. As in the time it arrived on the computer your mail program is installed on. Keeping with the mail analogy, the mail server is your local post office and your email client is you mailbox. Webmail clients muddy this a bit as the message handling portion of the webmail client is often running on the same machine as the mail server. As a result, the webmail client tends to report the received time as being very close to the time at which the mail server received the message.

Answer (score 1):

> In Outlook, the same email did not show up until after `Tue, 3 Mar 2020 00:00 UTC` when Outlook is restarted.

That doesn't sound expected, but there could be reasons for it (e.g. if Outlook was in offline status, or network issues). You can ask G Suite support to investigate, but it's not always visible in GSSMO logs, so they might not be able to give you a certain answer.

> In Outlook, instead of showing the actual time of receipt, it shows `Mon, 2 Mar 2020 01:33 UTC` as the date of receipt. Which is even before Gmail receives the mail. I am not sure whether this is the Sender's machine time, or the actual server time.

Outlook has two timestamp fields in the UI - the sent time (from the `Date` header, possibly rounded to the closest minute), and the received time (when the message was received by Outlook). Please check if there's another timestamp field that you can use, which does have the real received time. As @Aidan noted, you can ask G Suite support to look into that as well.